# How do I create a new dataframe after performing a calculation on an existing one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe containing various customer details. It looks something like this:

```
customer_id  hours   sales
    1         5      20
    2         7      10
    3         2      16
    1         4      12
    3         4      15
```

I need to create a new dataframe that contains the total sales for each customer id. It should look something like this:

```
customer_id    total_sales
    1             32
    2             10
    3             31
```

I have been doing something like this:

```
 df2 = df['sales'].groupby('customer_id')
```

But I am not getting the above dataframe.

Comment: `df.groupby('customer_id', as_index=False)['sales'].sum()`